Next js rendering components before children
I have a layout component in my Next.js application that uses a Suspense component to wrap a PathProvider. The structure looks like this:
// ALL MY IMPORTS

const XYZcomponent = dynamic(() => import('@/c-component').then(mod => mod.XYZcomponent), {
  ssr: false
});

export default async function MyLayoutComponent({
  children
}: Readonly<{
  children: ReactNode;
}>) {
  const session: any = await getServerSession(options);
  if (!session) {
    return redirect('/login');
  }
  const response = await APIcall();
  if (!response?.data.is_success || response?.status !== 200 || !response.data) {
    return redirect('/login');
  }
  return (
    <>
    <Acomponent />
    <Bcomponent /> 

    {children}
    
      <Suspense>
        <XYZcomponent />
      </Suspense>
    </>
  );
}

Inside the children I have a page named <Apple />.
Inside <Apple /> I have text:

I'm the Apple.

And inside <XYZcomponent /> I have text:

I'm the XYZcomponent

Now when I click on a button to navigate to the Apple page, it shows XYZcomponent first. Although I have it bellow {children}, I want to render the children first and then my <XYZcomponent />
Thanks for your help!

Could you provide a link to an environment where the issue can be reproduced?
